# Move paid apps between devices?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

I have an android phone(1) on 2.3.3 and a tablet(2) on preorder that will be on 3. (And a bad gadget habit.)

Can I, when the tablet arrives, uninstall paid apps on the phone and install them on the tablet? It feels like I should be able to since I've paid for a copy of the app linked to that Google account it shouldn't matter which linked device it's on. (Why? Some stuff I've paid for will look better/be more useful on the tablet.)

I've looked online, but most people are asking about moving paid apps from broken phones (ie when they can't uninstall from the first device) or trying to run the same paid app on multiple devices which is piracy/cheap.

(1) nexus one
(2) xoom

Comment: As per Edelcom's answer, I believe google does allow you to run the same paid app on multiple devices.  So it's not piracy/cheap in this case :)

Comment: @sparx I don't believe so since this is about installing on two devices at once, the q you linked to appears to be about installing twice on the same device.

Comment: @syntheticbrain: part of the standard Android Market terms is that application are tied to the Google Account and not the devices. The Market terms is deliberately formulated to allow user to install a single paid app in as many devices that they own that uses the same Google Account. It is not necessary to uninstall the app in your other devices.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I bought an Anchor tabled last week , and using my Google account, was able to download the application I bought on my Samsung Galaxy S phone, without any problems.

So I think, from my experience, you can download the same software again, as long as it's coupled with the same Google account.

Comment: Correct, your apps are tied your Google account, not your phone

Comment: This works for me with a droid x and a xoom.

Answer (score 5):

After flashing CyanogenMod 6.2.1 to my phone I visited [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) and logged in and it showed all of my apps still "installed" on my phone before the flash (I didn't use any app backup software).  I clicked on each of my apps and clicked the install button and they all came over to my phone properly, including the few paid apps I have.

This leads me to believe that Android doesn't prevent the same apps (including paid apps) from being installed on more than one device so long as they are both associated with the same Google account.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you use the same Google mail account, you will find that on the market place the app will display as purchased. Therefore, allowing a free download of your paid for app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you set up your devices and your version of the market.

If both devices are set up using the same gmail address - no problems you have can download anything you have purchased to all devices (as its linked to your account).

Market versions v3 and older allow the use of multiple accounts. i.e. you can set up one account on one device i.e. phone, another gmail account on another device i.e. tablet. As long as you have linked these accounts in your google profile, then you can switch between accounts in the market and download from either account to your device.
(Quick easy way to know if you have this market is its look - its the one that looks like tiles i.e. the WinMobile look).