# Reinstalling purchased apps on a new phone?

Tags: applications, accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move paid apps between devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7099/move-paid-apps-between-devices)

My contract is getting close to finishing so I'll be upgrading to a new Android phone and giving my old phone to a family member.

When I move my Google account across to my new phone will I have to repurchase or just re-download my paid for apps?

Also will I'll have to remove the paid for apps from my old phone before it is associated with a new Google account?

Comment: Bonus question: If your old phone came with some app free that usually costs money, do you still have access to it / can use it on your new phone?

Comment: @user4188 mot usually because when the device comes with an app, it is installed on the device from the manufacturer and not via the android market.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will not have to repurchase them if you associate the same Google account with the new device. They will be available in your market to re-download.

I don't know if you can have more then one phone associated with the same account, but I did not do anything when I got a new phone, except associate my google account to the new phone.

Comment: This is correct.  You can have more than one phone with the same account.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to re-download them, not re-purchase them.  The apps are tied to your account, not your device.

As far as I know you don't have to do a thing to your old device before your apps are available for download and installation on your new one.

[Post #2 in this thread](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/35053-moving-apps-new-phone.html#post251139) states the same, for what it's worth.

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon App Store also follows the same model. I had to switch to a different ROM after clearing cache and reinstall on my NotionInk Adam Tablet. Through the browser I reinstalled the AmazonAppStore App. I used the same amazon UserID and passwd. It immeidately recognized all the apps I had purchased and provided option to download and re-install them.