# If I buy a software and change smartphone, should I buy it... AGAIN?

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reinstalling purchased apps on a new phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9422/reinstalling-purchased-apps-on-a-new-phone)

I've just tweaked my Google Play application to believe I have an HTC Desire S so I can buy all the games that I can't buy with my Acer Liquid Metal.
No problem with that...
Then I saw that all my old purchased software was not purchased.

Now two solutions are there:

1. I just made an happy mess --> no problem.
2. If you buy any app for your phone and then buy a new one you should buy that app... AGAIN?!?!

Comment: As long as you're using the same account they're supposed to be considered "purchased" (see, for example, [Reinstalling purchased apps on a new phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9422)).

Comment: All Google Play purchases are tied to your gmail account. If you use the same account for both phones, then you should be fine.