# Upgrading my phone - what happens to the apps?

Tags: applications, updates

I've got an HTC Incredible 1, going to be upgrading to a Rezound.  How do I get the apps (both free & purchased, some on the SD some on the phone) from my Incredible to the Rezound?  Free isn't that big a deal, I can re-download them, but I don't want to re-purchase anything.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move paid apps between devices?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7099/move-paid-apps-between-devices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you log in to the new device with the same google account that you use on the Incredible you will have access to all the apps that you purchased / downloaded. You will not have to purchase them again. The android market is tied to your google account, not the device.

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to double-check.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that any free apps you downloaded through Google Market are not "tracked" in Market and will not show up in your My Apps list in Google Market, so if you wanted to keep those, you'll need to use a backup app or make a list so you can find and re-download them easier.  Only the paid apps will show up when you log in from the new phone.  There is a way to find the full list of apps you've downloaded through the Market web interface, but not in the Market app.

Comment: @BBlake My free apps get restored, without a backup program, but I also set the device to "sync" or backup with google services when I set up the device. I don't know where that setting is except during the first setup. Also you can see your entire history, paid and free, in the online market under [My Library](https://market.android.com/mylibrary?shelf=apps&feature=top-nav)

Comment: Interesting.  My free apps never do when I do a reset.  But it is an older phone and only has Froyo.